# How can I avoid libgdx SpriteBatch/BitmapFont breaking Texture.bind?

Tags: java, libgdx

```
Gdx.gl10.glPushMatrix();
Gdx.gl10.glTranslatef(center.x, center.y, 0);
Gdx.gl10.glRotatef(0, 0, 1, angle * 360f / (2f * (float)Math.PI));
texture.bind();
mesh.render(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
Gdx.gl10.glPopMatrix();
```

...and here is some code that draws a bit of text:

```
spriteBatch.begin();
spriteBatch.setColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
float fps = 1f / Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
font.draw(spriteBatch, "fps: " + fps, 0, 50);
spriteBatch.end();
```

The first bit of code works, frame after frame, until the second bit of code runs. After that, the first bit's triangle strip is rendered using only the latest glMaterial. Any idea why this is happening? What should I do to keep both materials in drawing ('texture' for mesh and its sprite texture, that should be different)?

Comment: I removed some of your tags as they didn't seem to strongly relate to your question. Feel free to edit some back in that you feel describe the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SpriteBatch#end()` has to disable blending and texturing as it assumes a clean GL state context on a call to `SpriteBatch#begin()` and restores that clean state context on `SpriteBatch#end()`. In your case, you simply have to enable texturing via `glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D)` before you render your mesh.

When in doubt check out the SpriteBatch javadocs which tell you about the GL state changes it makes.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem and my solution was to set the active texture back to GL_TEXTURE0 before letting SpriteBatch (or in my case scene2d) do its stuff:

```
Gdx.gl20.glActiveTexture(GL20.GL_TEXTURE0);
```